# How to add a LicenseKey to an Webservice Call in a BizTalk SendPort?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I need to communicate with a web-service but need to pass a License Key.

I generated the schema but my mapping requires me to map to the "OrderInfoObject" node.

[image: auto generated schema]

I tried creating a mapping that adds the soap envelope with license key and this creates code that works when I copy it into soapUI but gets double encapsulated (`<soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body>`) even if I set the inbound message body to Envelope -- entire from Body -- contents.

So my mapping has the following

```
 <wms:OrderInfoObject>
   ...
 </wms:OrderInfoObject>
```

And the send port adds that in the body of the soap

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="..." xmlns:wms="...">
  <soapenv:Header>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
 -- Here comes my message --
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The send port was generated by consuming the WSDL so I am not confident in how it works but the Header seems out of reach.

So I am unsure how to add the License key.

Comment: That's schema does not look right, it has multiple root nodes.  Have you edited the schema to tell BizTalk what the root node is?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf The schema was generated by consuming the wsdl. when i use the schema in a mapping, biztalk tells me to pick a root node in a multi root node schema. If i pick OrderInfoObject as root, the message i sent is perfect except for the LicenseKey (Since the license key is in the soap header and the orderinfoobject in the soap body)

Comment: I also added a sample of how my mapping aproaches the schema.

Comment: You can also edit the schema to give the Root Name name in the schema editor,  Then when you view it in Visual Studio it will display the proper hierarchy as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're focusing on the wrong appearance of LicenseKey.  You need to find the descendant implementation somewhere under OrderInfoObject.

It's unlikely there's anything wrong with the Schema as any number Elements can be defined at the root, then referenced somewhere under the 'real' root element.

To clean thing up, you can set the Root Reference on this Schema to OrderInfoObject, then all the 'Type' elements will be hidden.

*However*, if LicenseKey needs to be a SOAP Header element, you would use the WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders property to add elements to that section.

This MSDN Article describes the process: [Using SOAP Headers in WCF Messages with Orchestrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb246026.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: i might be focussing too much on the LicenseKey in the schema. It isn't avaible anywhere else except at the spot you can see it in the screenshot.

Comment: But the point of it is to be the security part, i need the LicenseKey to be in the soap header to get the message to validate. How would could i add a licence key to the soap header?

Comment: If LicenseKey needs to be in the Header, that's different.  And it really should not be in the Schema (doesn't matter one bit, it's just...not right...)

Comment: The schema was created by consuming the webservice though, will changing it make the webservice still recognise it?

Comment: Why would you change it?  If you mean the Root Reference, no, that's is just a BizTalk Designer Property and has no effect on any outside operations.

Comment: Oh, i tought you meant that the LicenseKey shouldn't be in the schema. I'm going to follow your Link on how to add it now.

Comment: The answer i was looking for was the data from the link. Would it be possible to add the example to your answer in case the link dies? outboundMessageInstance(WCF.OutboundCustomHeaders) = "<headers><Origination>Home</Origination><Destination>Work</Destination></headers>"

Comment: Your comment works well and Microsoft is pretty good about maintaining links so I wouldn't worry about that too much.